# datepicker ui not working correctly on edit page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

Am using datepicker ui for selecting Start date and End date.Its working correctly on create page.. But not working correctly on edit page.When i click start date in edit page, end date automatically got empty. Am using the following javascript.
css and js file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

My view:

```
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="from"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="to"></p>
```

view error screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwtiH.png
when i click start date it default highlighted and shows the current date only.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwtiH.png
after select start date, automatically end date becomes empty.. and also defaultly shows 2020 year..

Comment: Have you checked what `selectedDate` is inside the event?

Comment: how to check the selectedDate in inside the event? @artm

Comment: console.log(selectedDate) and check your console.

Comment: console.log is empty.. @artm

Answer (score 0):

import 
jquery-1.10.2.js
jquery-ui.js
jquery-ui.css
and you code will start running

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: i use the above css and js files.